# How to split pandas data with years in index and months in columns (percent change)

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get percentage changes per month/year so that I see years in index and months in columns.

Here's how the original data looks like:

```
time
2009-12-31    1.692868
2010-01-03    1.693478
2010-01-04    1.681354
2010-01-05    1.681792
2010-01-06    1.676942
2010-01-07    1.685896
2010-01-08    1.675619
2010-01-09    1.675620
2010-01-10    1.671965
2010-01-11    1.668323
```

I have further used the following formula to obtain monthly percentage change.

```
prices.resample("M").ffill().pct_change().apply(lambda x: round(x*100,2))
```

Here's the data I received:

```
time
2009-12-31     NaN
2010-01-31    1.32
2010-02-28    0.48
2010-03-31   -0.49
2010-04-30    0.11
2010-05-31    4.45
2010-06-30   -1.30
2010-07-31   -4.09
2010-08-31    1.08
2010-09-30   -3.72
2010-10-31   -1.91
2010-11-30    2.93
2010-12-31   -3.42
2011-01-31    0.14
2011-02-28   -0.83
2011-03-31   -0.40
2011-04-30   -3.91
2011-05-31    0.88
2011-06-30   -0.34
2011-07-31   -2.66
```

However, my final goal is to have percentage changes per each month,  **so that I have years in index and months in columns.** How can I do it? I would appreciate any advice. Also, I am wondering how to build a similar heatmap with matplotlib.

Here's an example of what I need.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar objective a while ago and solved it using the groupby method. You do have to use an aggregation function (I used `mean()`), but since you have only single values for every month and year already this method is a bit inefficient, but it does still work for your case.

```
df["month"] = df.index.month


# Have a dataframe named df with a month column, and group it by year 
df2 = df.groupby([df.index.year, 'month'])[1].mean().unstack()
print(df2)
```

This gives this output:

```
month    1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9     10    11    12
0                                                                            
2009    NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
2010   1.32  0.48 -0.49  0.11  4.45 -1.30 -4.09  1.08 -3.72 -1.91  2.93 -3.42
2011   0.14 -0.83 -0.40 -3.91  0.88 -0.34 -2.66   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Now I do not use matplotlib, but using [plotly](https://plotly.com/python/) you can make a heat-map quite easily from this:

```
months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'] 
times = list(df.index.year.unique())
fig2  = go.Figure(data=go.Heatmap(
        z=df2,
        x=months,
        y=times))
fig2.update_xaxes(title_text='Months')
fig2.update_yaxes(title_text='Years',dtick=1)
fig2.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can obtain your graph directly without the first step:

As your example is a bit short, let's use this dummy one:

```
dates = pd.date_range('2009-01-01', '2020-12-31')
df = pd.DataFrame({'time': dates,
                   'value': np.random.random(size=len(dates)), 
                  }).set_index('time')
```

```
>>> print(df)
               value
time                
2009-01-01  0.661110
2009-01-02  0.757710
2009-01-03  0.490736
2009-01-04  0.148575
2009-01-05  0.715500
...              ...
2020-12-27  0.715620
2020-12-28  0.171634
2020-12-29  0.412512
2020-12-30  0.814756
2020-12-31  0.427202

[4383 rows x 1 columns]
```

#### processing:

Here we'll use `pivot_table` to reshape the data, taking the mean of the values, then we'll apply `pct_change`:

```
# just to get month names in order
cols = pd.date_range('2020', '2021', freq='M').month_name().str[:3]

df2 = (df.assign(year=df.index.year,
                 month=df.index.month_name().str[:3],
                 )
         .pivot_table(index='year', columns='month', values='value', fill_value=0)
         .pct_change()
         [cols]
      )
```

output:

```
month       Jan       Feb       Mar       Apr       May       Jun       Jul       Aug       Sep       Oct       Nov       Dec
year                                                                                                                         
2009        NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
2010   0.214070  0.065160 -0.073928 -0.013328  0.145379 -0.000346  0.118528  0.069972  0.037107 -0.249954 -0.244608 -0.087839
2011   0.031421  0.126091 -0.032321 -0.000812  0.004430 -0.084645  0.026099  0.020069  0.073262  0.087346  0.228409  0.093019
2012  -0.095717 -0.248492  0.094027  0.173968  0.307899  0.075966 -0.200719  0.030460 -0.185117  0.107859 -0.090682 -0.109882
2013   0.075015  0.242875 -0.049873 -0.195608 -0.144225  0.017974  0.311462  0.041423  0.277412 -0.113914  0.175273  0.045258
2014   0.018353 -0.113219  0.189669  0.064207  0.036269  0.022477 -0.232103  0.109159 -0.103024 -0.088224 -0.159047  0.067562
2015  -0.094678  0.186993 -0.128900  0.074652  0.054206  0.093470  0.111634 -0.053931  0.034411 -0.088852  0.181860 -0.055049
2016   0.057190  0.029102  0.011317 -0.051180 -0.181694 -0.084899  0.013056 -0.078995 -0.198341  0.377086 -0.096291 -0.181843
2017  -0.161556 -0.059750 -0.051224 -0.202536  0.165222 -0.086402  0.116095 -0.029666  0.224123 -0.010386 -0.081571  0.381159
2018   0.109618 -0.004155 -0.007470  0.251640 -0.100422 -0.113325 -0.161298 -0.107079  0.023862 -0.029307  0.070167 -0.144116
2019   0.027455 -0.189825  0.142514 -0.037071  0.100118  0.157974  0.020722  0.022490 -0.187602  0.168074  0.187713  0.209489
2020   0.014801  0.310334 -0.037249 -0.010381 -0.231910  0.012961  0.128481 -0.083552  0.186090 -0.055755 -0.102882 -0.020587
```

#### plotting

Let's use `seaborn.heatmap` to plot with the "vlag" colormap (blue/red is much better than green/red for colorblinds):

```
import seaborn as sns
ax = sns.heatmap(df2, cmap='vlag', center=0, annot=True, fmt='.2f')
ax.figure.set_size_inches(8, 6)
```

[image: pct_change heatmap]

Comment: The solution looks so smooth and clean. However, I get incorrect values for pct_change(). Do you know what can be the reason for it? I have -inf values too. Seems strange to me.

Comment: If you have 0 for a given year and a negative value the next year, pct_change will output -inf. Can you share your data?

Comment: thanks, here is the file with data
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_Taqmcfikisq66pKxIya2JM7-aOYDzLI/view?usp=sharing